# How do I have continuous dates and 0 values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I'm fairly new to Power BI and need a little help.
The data is as follows:

```
Task1 Completed Date          Count1
05/17/2021                      5
05/19/2021                      3
05/20/2021                      1
05/23/2021                      2
05/24/2021                      6
```

And so on, the data is from say 01/01/2016 till date. Some dates have 0 values, some have non 0 values.

The output I'm looking for is a continuous date table as follows:

```
Date                         Count1     Count2.....
05/17/2021                      5
05/18/2021                      0
05/19/2021                      3
05/20/2021                      1
05/21/2021                      0
05/22/2021                      0
05/23/2021                      2
05/24/2021                      6
```

There are multiple tasks and I want a common table with all these counts on the same table so that the count for each task can be compared and further calculations can be done.

Could someone please help me out in generating such a table.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Table with the Date column from your table in the value sections.

Drag the same column once more in the values section of the Table and set it to Date only, after that summarize the column by **Count**.

[image: Summarize]

Make sure to tick the `show items with no data` option in the date column(first date).

[image: Items with no data]

This will count and show the occurrence of a date in the whole table, and if you want to filter it out with some conditions then just drag the option to Filter Pane and the count will show accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may read up more on how to create date table in power bi. Essentially its just a serialized table with continuous dates so all your transaction dates can be related to.

[sqlbi date table tutorial](https://youtu.be/-li7sxUxEqA)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating a Calendar table and make a relation between your table and the Calendar. This is a MUST for almost every Power BI report. The DAX should look something like this:

```
Calendar =
   CALENDAR(
      MIN('YourTable'[Completion Date]),
      TODAY()
   )
```

Then go to the Relationships view and create a relationship between 'YourTable'[Completion Date] and 'Calendar'[Date].

You can then use directly the Date from the Calendar table for your charts and visuals.